Ghost folder keeps appearing in my file system
I have a folder named DraftManuscript that keeps popping up in my directory path: /home/Laptop/Documentseach time I reboot my laptop. I have tried to delete it normally, as well as using sudo rm -rf /home/Laptop/Documents/DraftManuscript, but to no avail.
I tried to check which process is generating this folder by running the command: lsof | grep "DraftManuscript", but I get the output:
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.

All this began when I upgraded my laptop from Linux Mint 21.2 to Linux Mint 21.3. I have tried to rollback the OS, but the problem now persists. What can I do to resolve this problem? Am I hacked?
I am using the 5.15.0-105-generic linux kernel, with Cinnamon 6.0.4 desktop environment.
